# I'm stuck in the void

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was dumb and used a command that sets my spawn in the void, and it's too far down to be able to fly out. I'm playing on PC. How do I get back?
(I'm in a Super Flat world.)

Comment: Hi loagn, please do not add your answer to your question. You can answer your own questions like anyone else, by posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you can type fast enough set your gamemode to creative so you dont take damage then teleport back to the top using the command enter preformatted text here `/tp (your name here) 0 ~ 0`

this should get you back to the surface. not sure about where your base is though

Comment: Going to creative will not save him. Instead of using 0 ~ 0, he could copy and paste "/tp @s ~ 300 ~ and falling from there.

Comment: I tried but It didn't work it keeps saying invalid command.